# Find the radius of three identical circles which touch each other externally.

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Three identical circles touch each other externally. The tangents at their point of contact meet at a point whose distance from any point of contact is 2 cm. The radius of the circles is?

Comment: Draw a diagram and find out at what angles the 3 common tangents meet. You will know what to do next..

Comment: Almost the same as this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838093/problem-on-circles-tangents-and-triangles/1838104#1838104

Comment: @almagest Seriously?? Almost same as that???? Nevertheless read what this kid has written below my answer...you will laugh.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty I said almost because I knew no closer would accept it as a duplicate.

Comment: @almagest I am not saying that...I am saying look at the questions the boy has asked below my answer...you really think he would get any idea from that answer?

Comment: I would have reasoned that $O$ was the centroid, so $AO=CO=2OE$, so $AO=4$, and hence $\text{radius}=AE=2\sqrt3$, which agrees with your answer. If I was more alert, I would have said $AE$ is the middling side of a 30-60-90 triangle so $2\sqrt3$. But however you look at it, it seems trap-free and simple. So +1

Comment: That kind of thing no longer surprises me. This site has everyone from lazy kids age 8 who want their homework done up to Fields Medal winners! To be fair maths is a subject where things tend to be impossibly difficult until the moment when they switch to being tiresomely trivial!

Comment: I'm the kid yet you're the one here begging to tick mark your answer when you don't know how to explain. Calls the triangle congruent first then says its a median, lol what is even median? 1:2 ratio? Wow. Anyway thanks for the effort, i'm not going to emulate you and shame you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Ok so $OE$ is 2cm and $AE$ is r. So, $AO=\sqrt{4+r^2}$. Similarly $CE=\sqrt{4+r^2}+2=\sqrt{3r^2}$. Solve it you get answer as $2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: How is CE=AO+2 ?

Comment: @Akshit $CE=CO+2$ and $CO=AO$ by congruence...and if you like my answer you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark left to my answer. If you have more doubts, feel free to ask.

Comment: i can't understand how the triangles are congruent? I am probably missing some basic stuff thats not striking.

Comment: @Akshit You don't even need congruence...see $\angle ACO=\angle CAO$ which means $AO=CO$. The angles are equal as angles $A,B,C$ are all $60^\circ$ and also $AO,BO,CO$ all bissect the angles as the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: There is no proof that the angles bisect each other. How are you coming to that?

Comment: @Akshit HOW CAN YOU SAY THERE IS NO PROOF?

Comment: i can't see how they bisect?

Comment: that does not mean there is no proof

Comment: Yeah sorry can you explain it?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-the-median-of-equilateral-triangle-is-also-angle-bisector See if this helps. Tell me if it doesn't, I will explain then.